# OpenGL instanced rendered objects not showing up on screen

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am trying to achieve per instance rendering in my Python project to display thousands of particles.

The relevant data for each particle is saved into one VAO looking like this:
[image: VAO]
With the texture coordinates in the top VBO, the next four VBOs containing the split-up model-view-matrix, the texture offset in the next and a blend factor for the particles in the last VBO.

In my Loader class I have 3 methods to create and update the VBOs:

```
class Loader:
    """
    This class creates and keeps track of all VAOs and VBOs and is responsible for binding them
    """
    __vaos = []
    __vbos = []
    __textures = []

    def create_empty_vbo(self, float_count: int) -> int:
        vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        self.__vbos.append(vbo)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, float_count * 4, None, GL_STREAM_DRAW)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        return vbo

    @staticmethod
    def add_instanced_attribute(vao: int, vbo: int, attribute: int, data_size: int, instanced_data_length: int,
                                offset: int) -> None:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
        glVertexAttribPointer(attribute, data_size, GL_FLOAT, False, instanced_data_length * 4, ctypes.c_void_p(offset * 4))
        glVertexAttribDivisor(attribute, 1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)

    @staticmethod
    def update_vbo(vbo: int, data: list[float]) -> None:
        data = numpy.array(data, dtype='float32')  # convert the data into a float32 array

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(data) * 4, None, GL_STREAM_DRAW)
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, len(data) * 4, data)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

In my ParticleRenderer class in the initializer i create the empty VBO and add the instanced attributes:

```
    def __init__(self, loader, projection_matrix: list[list]):
        self.__loader = loader
        self.__vbo = self.__loader.create_empty_vbo(self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH * self.__MAX_INSTANCES)
        self.__quad = loader.load_gui_to_vao(self.__VERTICES, 2)
        self.__loader.add_instanced_attribute(self.__quad.get_vao_id(), self.__vbo, 1, 4, self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH, 0)
        self.__loader.add_instanced_attribute(self.__quad.get_vao_id(), self.__vbo, 2, 4, self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH, 4)
        self.__loader.add_instanced_attribute(self.__quad.get_vao_id(), self.__vbo, 3, 4, self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH, 8)
        self.__loader.add_instanced_attribute(self.__quad.get_vao_id(), self.__vbo, 4, 4, self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH, 12)
        self.__loader.add_instanced_attribute(self.__quad.get_vao_id(), self.__vbo, 5, 4, self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH, 16)
        self.__loader.add_instanced_attribute(self.__quad.get_vao_id(), self.__vbo, 6, 1, self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH, 20)
        self.__shader = ParticleShader()
        self.__shader.start()
        self.__shader.load_projection_matrix(projection_matrix)
        self.__shader.stop()
        self.__pointer = 0
```

The VBOs get enabled in the prepare method like this:

```
    def prepare(self) -> None:
        self.__shader.start()
        glBindVertexArray(self.__quad.get_vao_id())
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(6)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glDepthMask(False)
```

And lastly the render method:

```
    def render(self, particles: dict, camera) -> None:
        view_matrix = Maths.create_view_matrix(camera)
        self.prepare()
        for texture in particles.keys():
            self.bind_texture(texture)
            particle_list = particles.get(texture)
            self.__pointer = 0
            vbo_data = [0] * len(particle_list) * self.__INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH
            for particle in particle_list:
                self.update_model_view_matrix(particle.get_position(), particle.get_rotation(),
                                              particle.get_scale(), view_matrix, vbo_data)
                self.update_tex_coord_info(particle, vbo_data)
                self.__loader.update_vbo(self.__vbo, vbo_data)
                glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, self.__quad.get_vertex_count(), len(particle_list))
        self.finish_rendering()
```

Also here is the Vertex Shader:

```
#version 140

in vec2 position;

in mat4 model_view_matrix;
in vec4 tex_offsets;
in float blend_factor;

out vec2 texture_coords_1;
out vec2 texture_coords_2;
out float blend;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform float number_of_rows;

void main() {

    vec2 texture_coords = position + vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    texture_coords.y = 1.0 - texture_coords.y;
    texture_coords /= number_of_rows;
    texture_coords_1 = texture_coords + tex_offsets.xy;
    texture_coords_2 = texture_coords + tex_offsets.zw;
    blend = blend_factor;

    gl_Position = projection_matrix * model_view_matrix * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

and the Fragment Shader:

```
#version 140

out vec4 out_color;

in vec2 texture_coords_1;
in vec2 texture_coords_2;
in float blend;

uniform sampler2D particle_texture;

void main() {

    vec4 color_1 = texture(particle_texture, texture_coords_1);
    vec4 color_2 = texture(particle_texture, texture_coords_2);

    out_color = mix(color_1, color_2, blend);

}
```

I had problems with the glBufferData and glBufferSubData functions in the `create_emtpy_vbo` and `update_vbo` functions.
Looking at the [Khronos documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) I suppose adding `None` as the parameter for the data argument fixed the problem.

Culling is not the problem, so isn't the texture.

Skimming through the VBO it contains the data I would expect.

I changed the update_vbo function to use a numpy array and casted the last argument of the glVertexAttribPointer function to a void pointer, which didn't fix the error.